# Amazon AWS - Windows Instance Setup

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, iis

I have a domain www.rentcars.sg which is pointed to the right DNS server and verified by someone else and is working correctly: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=362885#362885

However, even though I setuped the domain correctly on the server with IIS, it's not working correctly.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Is there any additional setup I need to make to get it working?

Server IP : 23.23.129.247

Using the internal IP, it works but not with the server ip with port/url.

Comment: Can you provide more details on "it's not working correctly"?

Comment: Basically, beside the fact that I setup the DNS correctly, setup the IIS like I always do, as usual... when I try to go to www.rentcars.sg it failed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem, but my approach would be:

1. Allocating [EC2 Elastic IP Address](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346).
2. Associating such an address with your running EC2 instance.
3. Pointing your domain name to this IP address.
4. Adding inbound TCP rule for all IP sources (0.0.0.0/0) in Security Group settings belonging to your EC2 instance.

Comment: According to the link i have provided, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=362885#362885, it is actually pointing to the right running instance already. 

"Your domain now appears to be successfully mapped to the instance."

Comment: I see. Well, your domain points to 23.23.129.247, which actually falls into Amazon's range. So to make it clear: If you run a browser on your EC2 instance and go to http://localhost, then you get what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I get what i expected. I got the page. Point 4 isn't right, sadly. :( As mentioned here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=362885#362885 inbound rule is done as well.

Comment: Then it must be something within IIS, have you checked your site bindings? (IIS Manager -> Sites -> [your site] -> Edit Bindings)

Comment: Site binding is done right, if you were to look at this image. Its actually right. www.limguohong.com/edc.png Any other potential blocker?

Comment: There isn't any. "#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2012-07-24 23:45:31
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2012-07-24 23:45:31 10.194.5.194 GET / - 3002 - 10.194.5.194 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 500 0 0 11279"

Comment: Notice that you have status 500 in the log, so it might be something within your application. Do you have some error logging place? Do you work somehow with Request.Url? Is your page behavior really independent of the actual hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that windows instances in AWS come with the software (windows) firewall enabled by default. Make sure that you have the correct firewall policies in place in the software firewall as well as the security group.

Comment: I added two sites on my IIS server and wasn't able to connect to the ones that did not run on port 80, so adding the ports to the firewall fixed the issue.